# Different compression for different extensions while creating a zip archive

Tags: zip

How to add a directory to a zip file with *.jpg files stored without compression and other files stored with maximum compression?

Comment: Probably compress the other files you want to compress first in a single archive then include it with the JPG files in an uncompressed archive ... AFAIK, I haven't come across a `zip` builtin way to do that selectively at once.